# Apache Zeppeline Spark interpreter not showing log messages of loaded JAR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, log4j

How can i enable the display of the log messages of a loaded JAR library in Apache Zeppeline's Spark interpreter output? For example, all the println() statements in the JAR are shown while the log4j statement are not shown. Please note that the JAR also has its own log4j.properties file included in the package. The log messages appear if invoked from the command line.

I tried executing the following before calling functions that invoke the log statements:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO)
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")
```

However it did not work.

Comment: I also would like to have an answer to that.  I load a jar inside zeppelin and spark dependencies.  This jar output some logging information (to the console given spark_home/conf/log4j.properties) but I don't see it in the paragraph output.